# Issue with using global key in pageview items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

There are three levels of widgets in my app(as example).

Higher level: _HomePage <------- returns PageView widget

Middle level: _PlayerPage <------- page item (Container)

Lower level: _YoutubePlayer <------- YoutubePlayerFlutter Widget (Plugin)

The pageview is scrollable vertically and it switches page as user scrolls. 
The YoutubePlayer widget uses GlobalKey therefore scrolling and switching between pages works very smoothly and fast in performance. However there is one issue with this. If user fails turning a page, but only half way scrolled so it comes back to original position, it causes GlobalKey duplication error and messes up the element's lifecycle because the page turning event still gets triggered even though turning page fails but as soon as the user starts dragging, and that creates new widget with same global key before the previous element's lifecycle goes unmounted as it states in document:

> An element can remain in the inactive state only until the end of the current animation frame. At the end of the animation frame, any elements that are still inactive will be unmounted.

After wrestling with the issue, I have tried some possible workarounds I thought it may resolve the problem:

1. Not using global key.
2. Using global key, but create a custom ScrollPhysics to prevent user from holding, or dragging page slowly. The user can only fling to turn pages.

.
.
Result:
1. If I do not use global key, it works well without throwing any error, but the overall performance gets slower and because of that, it causes another problem. The video loading time cannot catch swiping speed if swiping is repeated very quickly. Therefore some videos gets error while loading(but it won't break the entire app, only the video itself). Also, swiping gesture itself does not work smoothly as there was global key. I also have tried using UniqueKey instead, but it doesn't seem to be different to not using a key at all.

Conclusion: I think it is better using global key compared to not using it in performance aspect.

2. I have tried modifying minFlingVelocity and DragStartDistanceMotionThreshold. It looked like pageview scrollphysics was using two independent ways to turn pages: dragging & Fling. So it turned out adjusting fling velocity wasn't what I was looking for. But when I set DragStartDistanceMotionThreshold to the device screen's height, it could disable moving pages with slow dragging, but fling still works as I wanted. However other problems came up are, 
   1) Fling won't work in the reverse direction(in my case, up) so it's not possible to turn back to previous page.
   2) Somehow fling won't work repeatedly without giving a delay between flings(approximately 1 sec). So I have to like one fling, and then 1sec rest, and another fling. Besides it is not a good user experience, if user keep trying to fling repeatly, it still causes Globalkey duplication error.

Conclusion: This might be the best solution only if there is a solution for the two issues(disabled reverse fling & repeated flings), but I couldn't find a way to solve it.

Please let me know if you have any other workaround suggestion or solution for the problems. I appreciate it.
My simplified codes are as below:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:JustMusic/global_components/api.dart';
import 'package:JustMusic/routes/home/components/youtube_player.dart';
import 'package:JustMusic/utils/custom_scroll_physics.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  ScrollPhysics _pageViewScrollPhysics = new CustomScrollPhysics();
  final _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  PageView pageView;
  List<dynamic> _sources = [];
  int _previousPageIndex = 0;
  var _futureVideo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _futureVideo = Api.getVideoList();
    _futureVideo.then((videos) {
      _sources = videos;
      pageView = PageView(
          physics: _pageViewScrollPhysics,
          controller: _pageController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            if (index > _previousPageIndex) {
              print('page switched to $index (down)');
            } else {
              print('page switched to $index (up)');
            }
            _previousPageIndex = index;
          },
          children: []..addAll(_sources.map((_source) {
                return YoutubePlayerScreen(
                    source: _source, pageController: _pageController);
            })));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _futureVideo,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return pageView;
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return Center(
              Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class YoutubePlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  YoutubePlayerScreen({
    @required this.source,
    @required this.pageController
  });

  final PageController pageController;
  final dynamic source;

  State<YoutubePlayerScreen> createState() => _YoutubePlayerScreenState();
}

class _YoutubePlayerScreenState extends State<YoutubePlayerScreen> {
  var _controller = YoutubePlayerController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
          child: YoutubePlayer(
            context: context,
            videoId: YoutubePlayer.convertUrlToId(widget.source["videoUrl"]),
            flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
              disableDragSeek: true,
              autoPlay: false,
              mute: false,
              showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
            ),
            videoProgressIndicatorColor: Colors.amber,
            progressColors: ProgressColors(
              playedColor: Colors.amber,
              handleColor: Colors.amberAccent,
            ),
            onPlayerInitialized: (controller) {
              _controller = controller;
              _controller.cue();
              _controller.addListener(() {
                if (_controller.value.playerState == PlayerState.CUED) {
                  _controller.play();
                }
              }
            );
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

---

You can find source code of YoutubePlayerFlutter from here:
https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter/blob/master/lib/src/youtube_player.dart

---

Edit:
 I also had come up with another workaround, but didn't know how to implement. It is to load the YoutubePlayerWidget only onPageChanged. Because I have tested that dragging the page loads previous/next video, but does not trigger onPageChanged listener. The listener only gets triggered when a page is actually turned to previous/next page.